# OWIN authenticate MVC an web API together and individually

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api, owin

I'm building a web application which uses ASP.NET MVC and Web API. I started building it using the VS 2013 SPA template which use OWIN.
In this way, the MVC application uses the auth cookies and the web api the bearer token to authenticate. 
But both of them (cookie and token) are set up during the login.

Now I want that other clients can authenticate individually only using the web api to getting the token.

I tried more times making calls to the /token endpoint or the /account/authorize (which is set up in the SPA template), but with no happy results.

Do I have to configure OWIN in the other way, or what am I doing wrong?